# How to fix severe lag issues in Android

Tags: java, android-fragments

I've tried to replace an heavy XML file by a some code, using an `ArrayAdapter` that I've made. The layout's just as I expected. However, the time to load the `Fragment` is just way too long (at least 10 seconds). I keep receiving message like `I/Choreographer: Skipped 779 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Before using `Adapter`, I tried using `AsyncTask` or `Thread`, but made it less laggy.

According to the profiler, the 10 seconds gap is between the first `Fragment` being paused and the second `Fragment` being resumed.

The Second Fragment `onViewCreated`

```
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Hashtable<Integer, Integer> dico = new Hashtable<>();
        //region filling Dico
        dico.put(2002, R.array.anMD2002);
        dico.put(2003, R.array.anMD2003);
        dico.put(2004, R.array.anMD2004);
        dico.put(2005, R.array.anMD2005);
        dico.put(2006, R.array.anMD2006);
        dico.put(2007, R.array.anMD2007);
        dico.put(2008, R.array.anMD2008);
        dico.put(2009, R.array.anMD2009);
        dico.put(2010, R.array.anMD2010);
        dico.put(2011, R.array.anMD2011);
        dico.put(2012, R.array.anMD2012);
        dico.put(2013, R.array.anMD2013);
        dico.put(2014, R.array.anMD2014);
        dico.put(2015, R.array.anMD2015);
        dico.put(2016, R.array.anMD2016);
        dico.put(2017, R.array.anMD2017);
        dico.put(2018, R.array.anMD2018);
        dico.put(2019, R.array.anMD2019);
        dico.put(2020, R.array.anMD2020);
        //endregion
        final MySQLiteHelper help = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
        Resources res = getResources();

        final List<String> allExtensionsName = new ArrayList<>();
        //region filling allExtName
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2020)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2019)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2018)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2017)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2016)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2015)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2014)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2013)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2012)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2011)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2010)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2009)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2008)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2007)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2006)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2005)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2004)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2003)));
        allExtensionsName.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.anMD2002)));
        //endregion

        int[] maxs = getMaxs(allExtensions, help);
        int[] progress = getProgresses(allExtensions, help);

        ListView listView = mView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final StatAdapter statAdapter = new StatAdapter((Accueil) getActivity(),prepareAdapter(maxs, progress,
                allExtensionsName, dico), allExtensionsName);
        listView.setAdapter(statAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String[] s = statAdapter.getItem(position);
                if (s==null) return;
                if (!s[2].equals(""))
                    launchParticularStat(s[1],(ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar),
                            allExtensions[allExtensionsName.indexOf(s[1])]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the call from the first Fragment:

```
m.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    StatFrag stats = new StatFrag();
                    accueil.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.fragment_container, stats).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            });
```

Is there any reason for this to lag?
Thanks.

Comment: You should take any heavy computation task, off the Android UI Thread. Like database communications, it depends on the app but for instance, you could call an async task, show some placeholders with animations and wait for the task callback to update UI.

Comment: Thanks, I now use an AsyncTask, which looks better. However, the ten second gap is still present... Is there a way of updating the content of my Adapter in onProgressUpdate, rather than in onPostExecute? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I managed to find an answer.
I've used an AsyncTask, and it was still lagging. I finally realized that I could do some `Log.d` to see what took time... It was the `getMaxs` and `getProgresses` part. So I modified the function to get maxs and progress values one at a time in a loop, then `publishProgress` to update my `StatAdapter`.